# BubbleSort troubleshooting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, netbeans, bubble-sort

It is my first attempt to do sorting in arrays. I am looking in BubbleSort. I looked up many examples on the net. However, I could not get my bubble sort working. Below is a snippet of my code:

//Sort by StudentID (long variable)

```
public static void BubbleSort(Student[] st) {
    long tempID;   //holding variable

    for (int j = 0; j < st.length - 1; j++) {
        if (st[j] != null) {
            long studentID1 = st[j].getStudentID();
            if (st[j + 1] != null) {
                long studentID2 = st[j + 1].getStudentID();
                if ((st[j] != null) && (st[j + 1] != null)) {
                    if (studentID1 < studentID2) // change to > for ascending sort
                    {
                        tempID = studentID1;                //swap elements
                        studentID1 = studentID2;
                        studentID2 = tempID;             //shows a swap occurred  
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

//My main method

```
if (studentIndex >= 0) {
                    BubbleSort(studentList);

                    for (int i = 0; i <= studentIndex; i++) {

                        studentList[i].writeOutput();

                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("No sorting done");
                }
```

Comment: I recommend using `Comparable<T>` or `Comparator<T>` for the comparison and this algorithm for sorting your `T[]`/`Student[]`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Please define *not working*.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? If not, how is the result incorrect?

Comment: Bubble sort requires nested loop but you have just one.

Comment: I did not get an error. The results after running the function does not change anything in the array. Sorry for not stating it clearly in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap elements. Your code doesn't.
In addition you have to check if you had modifications in your for loop. If yes you have to repeat the procedure.

So change it as follow

```
public static BubbleSort(Student[] st) {

    Student temp;   //holding variable
    boolean changed = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < st.length - 1; j++) {
        if (st[j] != null) {
            long studentID1 = st[j].getStudentID();
            if (st[j + 1] != null) {
                long studentID2 = st[j + 1].getStudentID();
                if ((st[j] != null) && (st[j + 1] != null)) {
                    if (studentID1 < studentID2) // change to > for ascending sort
                    {
                        temp = st[j];  //swap elements
                        st[j] = st[j + 1];
                        st[j + 1] = temp;  //shows a swap occurred  
                        changed = true; 
                     }                   
                }
            }

        }
    }
    if (changed) {
        BubbleSort(st);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Daavide. However, I am confused with `st[j] = st[i];`. Do I include another `for-loop` for variable `i`?

Comment: @Daavide thank you for the answer, I changed `st[i]`to st[j+1]`and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sorry. I edit the comment to change it from st[i] to st[j + 1]